# SQL - Summing at every level by conditions in hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I had a question I am trying to solve in regards to summing from the lowest child in a hierarchy to the highest level provided (noted by an ID). Essentially, I am attempting to input an ID of a large container into a recursive function that calculates the values of the lower nodes and then traces them back up for that particular ID.

I was working on the hierarchy in a recursive CTE and was able to get to the point shown below:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[tree_from_id](@myid INT) RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (
    WITH tree_cte (id, ID_PARENT, VOLUME, nlevel, treepath)
as
(SELECT i.id, i.id_parent, i.VOLUME, nlevel = 1, cast(i.id as nvarchar(255)) as treepath
 FROM item i
 WHERE id = @myid

 UNION ALL

 SELECT i.ID, i.ID_PARENT, i.VOLUME, tc.nlevel + 1, cast(tc.treepath+' <- ' + cast(i.id as nvarchar(255))as nvarchar(255)) as treepath
 FROM tree_cte tc
 INNER JOIN
 item i ON i.id_parent = tc.id
 SELECT * FROM tree_cte
 )
GO
```

This allowed me to get the level of each item and display their hierarchy, done by calling the function like:

```
SELECT * FROM tree_from_id(215548)
```

where 215548 is the particular items ID.

I was looking to implement something similar for the item volumes, but I am unsure how to go about aggregating from the lower child and rolling up to their parents. I tried the same method as shown above, but, understandably, it started from the parent and added downward to the children.

Also, is there a way to go about adding cases that define whether or not to add that item's volume/use a different value for it's volume? For example - if the item has no children, take different dimensions for volume?

Thanks! I am trying to learn more about SQL and found this to be a particularly difficult problem for me.

Comment: Well, it can be just  `Select sum(volume) as total from tree_from_id(215548)` . Provide sample data and desired result otherwise.

Comment: As for the adding cases portion of the problem - is there a way to place this within the recursive cast? The sum(volume) would be incorrect if cases are not taken care of in the calculation. Is there a way to see if that particular item/id exists in a different table and then see add if so? I assume this would go in the cast. Also, this recursion takes volumes from top and adds them as it goes downward - is there a way to start at the child?

Thanks Serg!

Comment: Yes you can go from child up , just reverse ON : `ON i.id = tc.id_parent`. Yes you can join `tree_from_id(...)` with other data , it can be treated as a regular table in SELECT.

Comment: Just tried and will see if I can work around the hierarchy. Any idea about adding conditions for recursion?

Comment: Condition in a recursion is meant to break recursion at a proper step, not to skip the step and continue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's volume that you want to accumulate, but can't you just sum it as you go?

Partial snippet....

```
UNION ALL

SELECT i.ID, i.ID_PARENT, i.VOLUME+tc.VOLUME, tc.nlevel + 1, cast(tc.treepath+' <- ' + cast(i.id as nvarchar(255))as nvarchar(255)) as treepath
FROM tree_cte tc
```

Comment: This seems to go from bottom to top though - do you know of a method that allows summing from the bottom-most child upward? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how you could add from the lowest level up.  For example, if you had a parent with two child nodes of differing values, what value would the parent node get?

Comment: The parent would get the sum of the values, unless stated otherwise in a condition. Essentially, the calculation rule in place is that for each parent, the parent's value is the sum of the children's values. That is the basis of the calculation, while other conditions would account for some exceptions. Do you know of a way to do that without using cursors?

Comment: I see your trouble.  This is a little beyond my capability, but perhaps you can adapt the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233946/using-bottom-up-or-top-down-search-to-find-the-best-path-from-hierarchical-data  to your case to use a bottom-up approach.  Of course, you would also have a to keep a sum of child nodes and join that table in as well.  Not trivial to be sure.